# How to extend Sitecore WFFM to include label?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

I want to create a field in `WFFM` to be able to add some text (with RTE). I've found [something similar](https://sitecoring.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/fancy-a-label-in-your-sitecore-wffm-form/) but it doesn't allow `Rich Text Editor`.

- Sitecore 7.2 WFFM 2.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another VisualFieldType attribute for your label. *VisualFieldType(typeof(CssClassField))* is not enough. It should be:

```
[VisualFieldType(typeof(TextAreaField))]
```

Examples, how to use it you can get [here](http://elenazlateva.blogspot.com/2012/09/custom-field-type-for-sitecore-web.html) and [here](http://sitecoresolutions.blogspot.com/2012/01/web-forms-for-marketers-email.html).